# Define a bijective mapping from a square to a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, transformation

I recently ran into a computer science problem that asked to uniformly generate random points within a circle. There's numerous algorithmatic ways to achieve this, but I'm interested in some form of a mapping.

My idea is, since generating uniform random points within a square is easy, can one explicitly define a bijective mapping from a square to a circle? (Or any shape to a circle).

If yes, what would be the mapping? Is it linear? And how would one go about defining these explicit mappings in the general case; i.e. given a domain subspace and a codomain subspace, how can one arithmetically find a mapping beyond just "looking at it"?

EDIT: Overlooked issue is, of course, the distribution in the circle also needs to be uniform

Comment: An important point that you may have overlooked: applying some bijection to your uniform distribution on a square will yield *some* distribution on the circle, but it need not be the uniform distribution.

Comment: right, I forgot to mention that

Comment: Note that if you know how to generate uniformly random points on some shape (say, a circle) using two variables $x_1, x_2$ chosen uniformly at random in $[0,1]$, then you are done, since the points  $(x_1, x_2)$ give the square $[0,1]^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a point $(x,y)$ chosen uniformly at random on the unit square, take $r = \sqrt x$ and $\theta = 2\pi y$. Going backwards, given $(r,\theta)$, take $x = r^2$ and $y = \frac\theta{2\pi}$.

Comment: Polar coordinates are a good idea but I think you need some normalization factor to have a uniform distribution in the circle.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, that is why $r = \sqrt x$ and not $r = x$.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd personally prefer to also repeat, and say that from square $(0,0)-(1,1)$ to unit circle use $\left (\sqrt{x} \cos(2\pi y) ,\, \sqrt{x} \sin( 2\pi y) \right )$; and for the inverse, using the `atan2()` function provided by most programming languages, $\left ( x^2 +  y^2 ,\, 0.5 + atan2(y, x) / (2 \pi) \right )$.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can do this. Firstly the problem with a bijection is that it won't necessarily preserve the uniform distribution. Anyway, here's my approach that came to mind first.

1. Probably the easiest approach is restricting the square. It's not a bijection, it's just the identity map $Id:\bigcirc\rightarrow\square$. You then consider $Id^{-1}(\square)$

Start by generating a collection of points randomly on a square. Then you check to see if the point lies in the circle - if it does, you keep it. If it doesn't, you discard it. More specifically, let's say you randomly generate points in a $1\times 1$ square centred at $(0,0)$. Then you randomly generate points $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...\}$. Each $a_i$ is of the form $a_i = (x_i, y_i)$. Now you know that $a_i$ lies in the circle only if $x_i^2+y_i^2 < r^2 = 1/4$. So your code will look like:

1. Generate a set of points randomly in a $1\times 1$ square.
2. For each point $(x_i,y_i)$, compute $x_i^2+y_i^2$.
3. If $x_i^2+y_i^2 < 1/4$, add $(x_i,y_i)$ to a new set, which corresponds to points radnomly generated by a uniform distribution on the circle.

You know this "map" doesn't interfere with the distribution because it's just the restriction of a square onto the circle.

Comment: This is known as [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). Although this is relevant, it is not really answering OP's question since s/he stated that s/he is aware of other algorithmic ways to achieve this, and is in particular interested in a bijection that preserves uniformity.

Comment: this is certainly a easy way to generate a uniform circle but I'm interested in a mapping.